# Error While caling Python function from Node.js express

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, express, node-modules

Tried searching forms , but could not find solution, Any help here is much appreciated.

Trying to call Python from node express , but getting below error.

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell')

PythonShell.run('script.py', options,function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('finished');
});
```

OR

```
PythonShell.run('script.py',function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('finished');
});
```

ERROR

```
function extend(obj, ...args) {
                     ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:414:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (P:\html\testPy.js:1:81)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
```

Comment: What's the version reported from `node --version`?. The package is a recent upload and simply a hasty wrapper executing python on the command line. The target JS is ES6 compatible only

Comment: @NeilLunn - Node version is - v4.2.2 . Thanks again

Comment: Node V4 is not ES6 compatible. If you want to use this module to need to upgrade your node version. Otherwise read many existing answers showing you how to execute a command from node.

Comment: @NeilLunn - thanks for the update , might not be able to upgrade. any forum u are aware of which has worked or has solution for python in  v4 ?